# true / false in input (vuejs), probably without v-model

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have an array with many checkbox.

```html
      <li v-for='item in resultQuery' :key='item.id'>
        <label class='custom-checkbox'>
          <input type='checkbox' :value='item.id' v-model='checkBrands'>
          <span @click='loadProducts(item.seoName)>{{ item.title }}</span>
        </label>
      </li>
```

I need to get true or false (depends on checkbox). How can I do this without affecting the v-model? (Use it to transfer an array of selected checkbox).

Needed to trigger a specific mutation

```js
       .then((response) => {
          if(true) {
            this.$store.commit(
              'showFilteredList',
              response.data.items
            );
          } else {
            this.$store.commit(
              'deleteCheckboxItems',
              response.data.items
            );
          }
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can using `@change` on checkbox.

Example: https://codepen.io/koei5113/pen/ZEXLLgL

```html
<input type='checkbox' :value='item.id' v-model='checkBrands' @change="changeEvent">
```

```js
methods: {
    ...,
    changeEvent($event) {
        console.log($event.target.checked);
    }
}
```

In this example you can see your `v-model` still working and you still can check checkbox status by the change event.

Answer (score 1):

`v-model` ignore the `:value` in the input. You need to use `:checked` and `@change`

For example, and when you emit the change event use your function.

```html
<input type="checkbox" :checked="value" @change="changeArrayNotValue" />
```